# Squared characters(instead Arabic characters) issue on wkhtmltopdf

Tags: laravel-4, ubuntu-14.04, wkhtmltopdf

I've installed wkhtmltopdf on ubuntu 14.04 . It's partly working now. I said partly because, all pdfs which was created by wkhtmltopdf include squares instead of text?
I have checked The answer Explaining about centOS(sudo yum install urw-fonts libXext openssl-devel) but it didnt work in ubuntu.